# Spring reactive not in all application

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

I saw a lot of example of application who use spring reactive. In all of the example, application is never full reactive.

Like this one
https://github.com/venugopr/Misc/tree/master/Spring/Spring-Session

Ui use spring-web-flux, when user need to authenciate, it call gateway.

Login controller look like

```
@Autowired
AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

 
@PostMapping("/authenticate")
public ResponseEntity<LoginResponse> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {
     ....
}
```

AuthenticationManager is not wrote in a reactive way.

Is there any advantage to do this way?
It's surely not full reactive

Answer (score 4):

Not really. To take full advantage of the reactive stack it should be used throughout the complete application, from the REST API down to the database access.

Regarding `AuthenticationManager`  there is the reactive counterpart `ReactiveAuthenticationManager` (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/authentication/ReactiveAuthenticationManager.html) which is the one that you should use in a Spring-WebFlux application.